# How do i do sub processes properly with Python

Tags: python, subprocess

I am new to python so I'm in the early stages of learning it. I was wondering if anyone knows how to run a system command after another. It's hard to explain:

```
subprocess.call('dir',shell=True)
subprocess.call('cd ..',shell=True)
subprocess.call('dir',shell=True)
```

When I run the command I expect to see the directory which the file is run. Which was fine.

Then the second process I expect to go up a directory.

Then the third command I expected to see the higher directory. Which I didn't I just saw the first directory.

Could some one explain why it isn't working as I expected and what I should do to correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to change the working directory in python that can be accomplished simply by `os` module. You can find that documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html). I would suggest only using `subprocess.call` to call a script or another program that isn't trying to modify stuff based on the current environment.

Answer (score 1):

The general rule is that children cannot affect the parent's environment.

`subprocess.call` creates a child process.  The child process can do many things.  But, any changes it makes to the current working directory or to environment variables only last for the duration of the subprocess call.  After the call completes and control returns to the parent, the parent's environment is restored unchanged.

If you want the `cd` to affect the next `dir` command, you need to have both in the *same* child.  For example:

```
subprocess.call('cd ..; dir', shell=True)
```

You probably asked this question for more general purposes.  But, for the specific examples that you provided, note that those actions might be better performed with the `os` module, rather than the `subprocess` module: listing files in the current directory can be done with `os.listdir` and changing the current working directory can be done with `os.chdir`

Answer (score 0):

When you run a subprocess with `shell=True`, python starts up a new shell to run the command in. It is basically the same as if python start up a new command prompt, entered in the command, and then closed the command prompt.

The consequence is that any action which only affects the shell is lost when the shell is closed. So you can create files and you'll see that because the hard drive is changed. But if you change the current directory of the shell that change will be lost.

You might wonder about the output of the program. Basically, the default is for the output of the program to be copied to the output of the calling program. (You can override this.)

If you want to change the current directory you want `os.chdir`. In general, you should avoid calling subprocesses and prefer python's tools. For example, instead of `dir` use `os.listdir`.